# How do I total numbers in a MS Excel 2010 cell when criteria in other cells are met?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to total the sum of range of cells once three criteria is met but I am not having any success getting the formula to work.For example, if cells A7 thru A846 are yes, and cells b7 thru b846 have the letter C and e7 thru e846 are greater than 0 then I want to add the values of e7 thru e846 that meet the criteria. Everything I have tried so far with countifs and sum expressions has not worked.Please help!

Comment: please add, what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

[I think what you want is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271347/is-this-what-you-want-answers):

```
=SUMIFS(E7:E846,A7:A846,"yes",B7:B846,"C",E7:E846,">"&0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a column, F.
As F's formula, set it to your formula for a single row to pull E if the criteria are met, otherwise 0. e.g. =if(and(a7="yes",b7="C"),e7,0)

Then just sum F.